# building odcctools in a 64-bit OS

Tags: iphone, macos, compilation, darwin

The odcctools package provides binutils for the Darwin OS. -- this allows you to cross compile to Darwin and OSX for example. However, odcctools does not seem to build properly on 64-bit OSes:

```
./../expr.c: In function ‘expression’:
./../expr.c:311: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘n_name’
```

Or, if you set CFLAGS to `-m32`, you get this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../libstuff/libstuff.a when searching for -lstuff
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstuff
```

How do you build this on a 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the odcctools makeflags are set up, you can't use CFLAGS -- you have to set both CC *and* CXX:

```
CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" ./configure blah blah blah
```

Note that I had to add a `-fpermissive` to my CXX to get it to run but this may not be necessary!

Also, you may be interested in [this post](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/issues/detail?id=178) (although it wasn't sufficient for my setup).

(If anyone has a better way to do this please let me know!)